# WPF Toolkit: VisualStateGroup Bug?

Tags: .net, wpf, wpftoolkit, visualstatemanager

I am getting an odd intermittent bug that seems to ve related to the VisualStateManager in the WPF Toolkit. I am developing an application that uses the Toolkit (June 2009), but not the VisualStateManager. Nonetheless, I am getting the following error:

```
'TextColor' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid'.
```

Needless to say, I am not trying to change a TextColor property on a Grid control.

The exception doesn't point to any particular line in my source code. Instead, it points to a line in the VisualStateManager--I have copied the IL dump below. I have also posted the full text of the exception.

Has anyone else come across this problem? Thanks for your help.

```
***************************************
EXCEPTION TEXT
***************************************
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  Message="'TextColor' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid'."
  Source="PresentationFramework"
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.ResolveTargetName(String targetName, INameScope nameScope, DependencyObject element)
       at System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.ClockTreeWalkRecursive(Clock currentClock, DependencyObject containingObject, INameScope nameScope, DependencyObject parentObject, String parentObjectName, PropertyPath parentPropertyPath, HandoffBehavior handoffBehavior, HybridDictionary clockMappings, Int64 layer)
       at System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.ClockTreeWalkRecursive(Clock currentClock, DependencyObject containingObject, INameScope nameScope, DependencyObject parentObject, String parentObjectName, PropertyPath parentPropertyPath, HandoffBehavior handoffBehavior, HybridDictionary clockMappings, Int64 layer)
       at System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.BeginCommon(DependencyObject containingObject, INameScope nameScope, HandoffBehavior handoffBehavior, Boolean isControllable, Int64 layer)
       at System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.Begin(FrameworkElement containingObject, HandoffBehavior handoffBehavior, Boolean isControllable)
       at System.Windows.VisualStateGroup.StartNewThenStopOld(FrameworkElement element, Storyboard[] newStoryboards) in C:\dd\WPF_1\src\wpf\src\ControlsPack\WPFToolkit\VSM\VisualStateManager\System\Windows\VisualStateGroup.cs:line 109
       at System.Windows.VisualStateManager.GoToStateInternal(Control control, FrameworkElement element, VisualStateGroup group, VisualState state, Boolean useTransitions) in C:\dd\WPF_1\src\wpf\src\ControlsPack\WPFToolkit\VSM\VisualStateManager\System\Windows\VisualStateManager.cs:line 234
       at System.Windows.VisualStateManager.GoToState(Control control, String stateName, Boolean useTransitions) in C:\dd\WPF_1\src\wpf\src\ControlsPack\WPFToolkit\VSM\VisualStateManager\System\Windows\VisualStateManager.cs:line 67
       at Microsoft.Windows.Controls.ButtonBaseBehavior.UpdateState(Control control, Boolean useTransitions) in C:\dd\WPF_1\src\wpf\src\ControlsPack\WPFToolkit\VSM\VisualStateManager\Microsoft\Windows\Controls\ButtonBaseBehavior.cs:line 77
       at Microsoft.Windows.Controls.ControlBehavior.UpdateStateHandler(Object o, EventArgs e) in C:\dd\WPF_1\src\wpf\src\ControlsPack\WPFToolkit\VSM\VisualStateManager\Microsoft\Windows\Controls\ControlBehavior.cs:line 54
       at MS.Internal.ComponentModel.PropertyChangeTracker.OnPropertyInvalidation(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
       at System.Windows.DependentList.InvalidateDependents(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs sourceArgs)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, OperationType operationType)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyPropertyKey key, Object value)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyPropertyKey dp, Boolean value)
       at System.Windows.ReverseInheritProperty.FirePropertyChangeInAncestry(DependencyObject element, Boolean oldValue, DeferredElementTreeState treeState)
       at System.Windows.ReverseInheritProperty.FirePropertyChangeInAncestry(DependencyObject element, Boolean oldValue, DeferredElementTreeState treeState)
       at System.Windows.ReverseInheritProperty.FirePropertyChangeInAncestry(DependencyObject element, Boolean oldValue, DeferredElementTreeState treeState)
       at System.Windows.ReverseInheritProperty.FirePropertyChangeInAncestry(DependencyObject element, Boolean oldValue, DeferredElementTreeState treeState)
       at System.Windows.ReverseInheritProperty.OnOriginValueChanged(DependencyObject oldOrigin, DependencyObject newOrigin, DeferredElementTreeState& oldTreeState)
       at System.Windows.Input.MouseDevice.ChangeMouseOver(IInputElement mouseOver, Int32 timestamp)
       at System.Windows.Input.MouseDevice.PreNotifyInput(Object sender, NotifyInputEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
       at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
       at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority priority, Delegate method, Object arg)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
       at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run()
       at ProjectManager.App.Main() in D:\Users\dcveeneman\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\FsProjectManager\ProjectManager\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

---

VS 2008 DISSASSEMBLY

---

```
Address: Microsoft.Windows.Controls.ControlBehavior.UpdateStateHandler(object, System.EventArgs)

Dissassembly: (VS 2008 caret indicates exception thrown at line 70, the NOP)

    --- C:\dd\WPF_1\src\wpf\src\ControlsPack\WPFToolkit\VSM\VisualStateManager\Microsoft\Windows\Controls\ControlBehavior.cs 
    00000000  push        ebp  
    00000001  mov         ebp,esp 
    00000003  sub         esp,10h 
    00000006  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],ecx 
    00000009  mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],edx 
    0000000c  cmp         dword ptr ds:[0BB401C8h],0 
    00000013  je          0000001A 
    00000015  call        53D8DC91 
    0000001a  xor         edx,edx 
    0000001c  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0Ch],edx 
    0000001f  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-8] 
    00000022  mov         ecx,55BDE49Ch 
    00000027  call        53B3F332 
    0000002c  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0Ch],eax 
    0000002f  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-0Ch],0 
    00000033  jne         00000063 
    00000035  mov         ecx,601D43E0h 
    0000003a  call        F1D25114 
    0000003f  mov         dword ptr [ebp-10h],eax 
    00000042  mov         edx,0BB40010h 
    00000047  mov         ecx,700001A9h 
    0000004c  call        53C84292 
    00000051  mov         edx,eax 
    00000053  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-10h] 
    00000056  call        51E0669C 
    0000005b  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-10h] 
    0000005e  call        53C843C7 
    00000063  push        1    
    00000065  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-0Ch] 
    00000068  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-4] 
    0000006b  mov         eax,dword ptr [ecx] 
    0000006d  call        dword ptr [eax+48h] 
    00000070  nop              
    00000071  mov         esp,ebp 
    00000073  pop         ebp  
    00000074  ret         4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't believe it. I found my answer right after I posted this question. Here's what happened: I created a control template for the WPF toolkit calendar control (I needed a calendar without navigation buttons). So, I modified a copy of the existing control template and sure enough, the control template does try to set a (non-existent) TextProperty on a layout Grid control. And it does occur inside a VisualStateGroup used by the original control template.

So, now all I have to do is figure out whether I introduced the bug when I modified the control template, or whether it was there before I started fiddling with it. In any event, mystery solved!

David Veeneman
Foresight Systems